# Ajax response to be a return value of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope, variable-assignment

In the below piece of code I am not getting the `locale` in the second alert

```
if `value==null`
```

I assign its `locale` value. but do not get it at the end.

```
function getLocale(id) {
    var locale="";
    var value = localStorage.getItem(id);
    if (value == null) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myUrl",
            data: {"new" : id},
            success : function(data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data)
                var id = data[0]["id"];
                delete data[0]["id"];
                localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(data[0]));
                locale=JSON.stringify(data[0]);
                alert(locale);//corrects value
            }// end success
        });
    }else{
        locale= localStorage.getItem(id);
    }
    alert(locale+"locale");//not have the value
    return locale;
}
```

Comment: ajax request is a async process which means it has a different timing with your function returning a value

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes this a possible duplicate it was just asked by the OP in a different way

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i need this function for return value

Comment: this post needs a retitle `Ajax response to be a return value of a function`

Comment: @LOL: Then read the answers to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not because of the scope. It is because of the asynchronous behaviour of ajax call. Because the function will not wait for the success event of ajax.

If you want to return, you should use `async:false` in ajax. But it is not a good method of coding.

Or you should restructure your code with the asynchronous ajax. Instead of returning the value, call a function in the ajax success with desired id.

Comment: what will be the solution

Comment: downvoter please comment. Then only I can improve my answer

Comment: Hey this answer is not supposed to downvote at all...he firstly answered and he is suggesting right .. please do not down vote unnecessarly

Answer (score 1):

**ajax request is an async process** which means **it has a different execution timing with your function** returning a value.

the trick here is **do not assume to have a return value in the scope of the function**.
**do all the process in the success call back function**

```
    success : function(data){
      //do everything what you want to do with the response here
    }
```

Comment: i need this function diffrent times, so i need to return value

Comment: you are doing it wrong if you push your self for a return value of an ajax request because ajax has a different timing(except if you will do `async:false` but it will lead you to more problems), what you can do is to call all the functions you need to process in the callback or else you will be leading yourself in a dirty way of solving your problem